# Do you have recommendations for printing tables based on analysis using lm_robust (OLS with clustered standard errors) and cjoint (AMCE-analysis)?

Tags: r

I have encountered some problems with printing my regressions in R with two different analysis. Usually I would use the stargazer to print the table and/or handle it in LaTeX, but stargazer doesn't work with the two regressions, and I am not using LaTex at the moment. I am looking for a package which can print the regressions nicely in HTML for my paper.

The first is a common OLS-regression in which I add clustered standard errors by using lm_robust from the estimatr package.

The second is a conjoinanalysis in which I use amce() from the cjoint package.

It may be a simple question, but some help would be greatly appriciated!

#EDITED

When I try to create a table based on my lm_robust regression analysis `regression201<-lm_robust(vaccination01~rodbla+sex+age_numeric+uddannelse+venstrehojre+taethed+PosPct, clusters=Id, data=dfsept)`

`summary(regression201)`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnDM9.png)

I then want to print it as a table in HTML using stargazer, but get the following error:

`stargazer(regression101,regression201,title="Villighed til at tage en anbefalet vaccine",align=TRUE, dep.var.labels=c("Villighed"), covariate.labels=c("Stemte på Socialdemokratiet","Stemte ikke ved sidste valg","Stemte rødt","Stemte ikke ved sidste valg","Mand","Alder +1","Uddannelse+1","Venstre-højre-skala+1","Befolkningstæthed+1","Positivprocent"), no.space=TRUE,digits=3,type="text")`

`% Error: Unrecognized object type.`

The same goes for trying to make an output table in HTLM-code with stargazer with my amce-analysis:

`results <- amce (CHOICE_INDICATOR~ER_PERSONEN_VACCINERET_MOD_COVID_19 + HAR_PERSONEN_OVERHOLDT_REGERINGENS_RETNINGSLINJER_FX_BRUGT_MUNDBIND_OG_UNDG_ET_ST_RRE_FORSAMLINGER_UNDER_COVID_19_PANDEMIEN + etnicitet + køn + ALDER + UDDANNELSESNIVEAU + BESK_FTIGELSESSTATUS_NUV_RENDE_ELLER_F_R_EVT_PENSIONSALDER+HVAD_STEMTE_PERSONEN_VED_SIDSTE_FOLKETINGSVALG, data=scenarieABC, cluster=TRUE, respondent.id="RESPONDENT_ID")`

`stargazer (results, title="Attributternes betydning for fortjenstfuldhed til behandling af COVID-19-senfølger",align=TRUE, dep.var.labels=c("Fortjenstfuldhed"), covariate.labels=c("Vaccineret mod COVID-19: Ja","Overholdt retningslinjer: Ja","Etnicitet: Ikke-dansk","Køn: Mand","Alder: Midaldrende","Alder: Gammel","Uddannelsesniveau: Erhvervsuddannet", "Uddannelsesniveau: Lang videregående uddannelse","Beskæftigelsesstatus: I arbejde","Stemte ved sidste valg: Blå blok","Stemte ikke ved sidste valg"), no.space=TRUE,digits=3, type=c("html"), style="ajps", out="Model1A.html")`

`% Error: Unrecognized object type.`

Comment: Hi! Could you add to your question in what way stargazer doesn't work and what is the desired output you expect? This way there's a better chance for people to give you better answers.

Comment: Hi! Yes, I added some code and more detail on the question :)